# Sampling from a bigger table in t sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sampling

I need to create a smaller table of customers (lets call it New_Table) from a full customers table (Full_Table).

All the customers have different ages. In my New_Table we need a certain age distribution, so when selecting customers for the New_Table I need to specify that we need 10% of customers from the group of "Under 15", 20% of customers from the group "15 to 24" and so on.

The problem is - exact percentages of customers that we need to take from each age group vary from report to report  - so in my query I cannot just specify the percentage of each group I need to select.

Is there any way I can  write a query where the required percentage of customers from each group is calculated via sub-query or is just taken from a separate table?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!!

Comment: Usually it helps to answer such questions if you include with your question a script that generates the table schema and inserts sample data into it. Also, provide expected output based on your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL Server 2008 for this example.

### Create table with sample data

```
DECLARE @Full TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), AgeGroup nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('Under 15');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('Under 15');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('Under 15');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('Under 15');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('Under 15');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('Under 15');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('Under 15');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('Under 15');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('Under 15');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('Under 15');

INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('15 to 24');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('15 to 24');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('15 to 24');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('15 to 24');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('15 to 24');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('15 to 24');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('15 to 24');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('15 to 24');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('15 to 24');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('15 to 24');

INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('24 to 35');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('24 to 35');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('24 to 35');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('24 to 35');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('24 to 35');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('24 to 35');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('24 to 35');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('24 to 35');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('24 to 35');
INSERT INTO @Full (AgeGroup) VALUES ('24 to 35');
```

This table has 10 rows for three age groups, 30 rows in total. Normally you would have a lookup table with the list of all possible age groups and in the Full table you'd have `AgeGroupID` instead of a text. For the sake of simplicity I'll use plain text.

You procedure would have a parameter - a table with Age groups and required percentage of each group.
I would make a stored procedure and pass a table-valued parameter into it. Here it is just another table in a script.

```
DECLARE @Params TABLE (AgeGroup nvarchar(50), Percentage float);

INSERT INTO @Params (AgeGroup, Percentage) VALUES ('Under 15', 0.1);
INSERT INTO @Params (AgeGroup, Percentage) VALUES ('15 to 24', 0.2);
INSERT INTO @Params (AgeGroup, Percentage) VALUES ('24 to 35', 0.4);
```

For each row in `Params` table we want to get some rows from the `Full` table. The `CROSS APPLY` effectively runs the given sub-query for each row in `Params`. The amount of returned rows is determined by the `TOP` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    @Params AS P
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(P.Percentage * 100) PERCENT
            F.ID
        FROM @Full AS F
        WHERE F.AgeGroup = P.AgeGroup
        ORDER BY F.ID
    ) AS CA_Full
;
```

This is the result set:

```
AgeGroup    Percentage    ID
Under 15    0.1           1
15 to 24    0.2           11
15 to 24    0.2           12
24 to 35    0.4           21
24 to 35    0.4           22
24 to 35    0.4           23
24 to 35    0.4           24
```

You can see that the number of rows for each age group corresponds to the given percentage.

To insert this result into a `New` table use standard `INSERT INTO New SELECT ... FROM ...`.

Comment: @Masha, how did you eventually solve the problem? Was my suggestion useful?